# Python 3.6 работа с буфером обмена

Tags: python, python-3.x, clipboard

Здравствуйте! Пишу приложение, которое определённым образом взаимодействует с буфером обмена. Чтобы пользователь был рад, доволен и счастлив, а его данные из буфера обмена не терялись хочу вынимать из из буфера, производить все нужные операции и вставлять обратно. Всё бы ничего, как вытаскивать и вставлять текст в буфер знаю(использовал `pyperclyp`, пробовал `tkinter`), но как только дело доходит до картинок в буфере обмена (`PrtSc`), хочется плакать. Он их стирает. Ошибок не вылетает (ну, не вылетает в `pyprclip`, `tkinter` ругается), ничего, просто после выполнения операции в буфере пусто. Вопрос: каким образом заставить программу вытаскивать и вставлять картинки?

Python 3.6.1/Windows 10

Comment: Похоже, не получится... В репозитории https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip -- "Currently only handles plaintext.". Попробуйте через Qt с буфером поработать. Вот [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/copy2clipboard.py)

Comment: @gil9red ну я догадался, что pyperclip не работает с текстом) Мне вот и интересно: каким образом вытаскивать картинки-то)

Comment: В Qt есть [QClipboard::image](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#image). Для питона это будут модули: pyqt4, pyqt5 и pyside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Работа с буфером обмена для изображений**

Запись  (Windows only):

```
from io import StringIO
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

filepath = 'image.png'
image = Image.open(filepath)

output = StringIO()
image.convert("RGB").save(output, "PNG")
data = output.getvalue()[8:]
output.close()

send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```

Сохранение изображения из буфера обмена:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
im.save('image.png','PNG')
```

**Работа с буфером обмена для текста**

Запись:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
c = Tk()
c.withdraw()
c.clipboard_clear()
c.clipboard_append('sample text')
c.update()
c.destroy()
```

Извлечение:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
c = Tk()
c.withdraw()
clip = c.clipboard_get()
c.update()
c.destroy()
print(clip)
```