# Как извлечь информацию из страниц по списку url с помощью python?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, web-scraping

У меня есть список urls. Список состоит из нескольких сотен urls.
Каждый из urls относится к отдельной странице со своей структурой, соответственно структура страниц по каждому из urls разная.

Я хочу написать алгоритм, который будет идти по списку страниц, витаскивать текстовую информацию со страницы и сохранять в какой-то файл. При чем, я не хочу, чтобы в файл сохранялись хедеры сайтов, футеры и другая вспомогательная информация.

Вот примеры url-ов:

- https://www.envistacom.com/envistacom-celebrates-veterans-stories-in-partnership-with-atlanta-united
- https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20180723005001/en/AKM-Has-Developed-Ultra-Low-Power-Step-up-DC-DC-Converter-in-Sensing-Technology
- https://www.blujaysolutions.com/blujay-helps-freight-forwarders-accelerate-digital-transformation-with-21-0-software-releases/

Проблема в том, что структура страниц разная и я не знаю, как извлечь текстовую информацию со страниц с разной структурой. Если бы структура страниц была одинаковой, решить задачу было бы просто, скажем с помощью Beautiful-soup.

Можно ли создать алгоритм, который будет извлекать информацию со страниц с разной структурой?
Какие библиотеки для этого можно использовать?

Comment: "алгоритм, который будет извлекать информацию"... что именно вы хотите извлекать?

Comment: хочу извлекать текст, только текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- возьмите [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/);
- скормите ему свой список из нескольких сотен urls;
- копируйте на каждой странице текст ([ctrl+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799440/to-send-threekeys-using-send-keys-in-selenium-python-webdriver));
- [сохраняйте буфер обмена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678634/python-3-6-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) в текстовый файл для дальнейшего использования...